# Using fileImporter to import cloud folders

Tags: swiftui, uttype, swiftui-fileimporter

I'm using [`fileImporter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/fileimporter(ispresented:allowedcontenttypes:allowsmultipleselection:oncompletion:)) to let the user select a folder:

```
.fileImporter(
    isPresented: viewStore.binding(\.$fileImporterPresented),
    allowedContentTypes: [.folder],
    allowsMultipleSelection: false
) { resources in
    // Do something
}
```

On macOS 13 (SwiftUI, not Catalyst) everything works as expected.

On iOS 16.1 it shows an open action for a folder but I cannot access Dropbox.

[image]
[image]

When I add additional `allowedContentTypes` like `.directory`, or `.volume` then Dropbox is no longer greyed out but it is also no longer possible to select a folder:

[image]
[image]

Selecting a folder seems to only work when the only `allowedContentType` is `.folder`.

How do I configure `fileImporter` to select a folder on an iOS external cloud storage provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with Dropbox not implementing `NSExtensionFileProviderSupportsPickingFolders`. That's why it's greyed out in the `fileImporter` but also in the `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

More information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71379422/225833